# Vagrant adds 'webroot' folder to my development enviroment

Tags: vagrant, puppet, vagrantfile

I am just starting to learn how to use vagrant for my development environment, and I've come across an annoyance.

When I `vagrant up` in the root directory of the project, it add's a `webroot` folder, this isn't what I'm after.

Vagrant gives me the following structure, with the random webroot folder, I think this is somthing to do with sym_links, but no amount of Googling gives me an answer

```
| ProjectName ~ Main Project Folder
-| .vagrant ~ Vagrant folder
-| puppet ~ Puppet Configuration Folder
-| vendor ~ Composer vendor folder
-| webroot ~ Randomly added folder :/
- .gitignore
- composer.json
- composer.lock
- Vagrantfile
```

My Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define "aws-control" do |namechase|
  end

  # Enable the Puppet provisioner, with will look in manifests
  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
    puppet.manifest_file = "default.pp"
    puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
  end

  # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  # Forward guest port 80 to host port 80 and name mapping
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 80

  config.vm.network "public_network",
                    ip: "192.168.0.61",
                    bridge: "en0: Ethernet"

  config.vm.hostname = "control.aws"

  # Synced Folders
  config.vm.synced_folder "/", "/vagrant/webroot/", :owner => "www-data"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing when assigning `config.vm.synced_folder` is you are mounting your entire host filesystem under the `/vagrant/webroot` directory.  Are you sure that's what you are intending to do?  Try mounting any other directory and you'll see that the `webroot` directory does not get created.

For example this will share the vagrant project directory and it works fine.

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant/webroot/", :owner => "www-data"
```

Comment: Thanks, I was somehow under the impression that was linked to the project root, and not the host root :)